# How do I show the title as well as URL on my share button on my blogger blog?

Tags: blogger

Here is the code I currently have for my custom share buttons for my blogspot blog:

```
<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url + data:post.title' target='_blank'><span class='share-box2'><i class='fa fa-twitter fa-2x'/><span><font size='3'>Share on Twittertop</font></span></span></a>
```

So when I click on the button on my blog a new window opens, but the twitter share box is empty, I need the Title of the post and the URL displayed. Why is it not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the data-tags and re-read [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button).
Correct use the Tweet button in Blogger:

```
<a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;text=&quot; + data:post.title' target='_blank'>
```